# Extracting day, month, year from HTML5 datepicker

Tags: html, datepicker

How do I extract day, month and year from the HTML5 datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`valueAsDate` property](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#dom-input-valueasdate) to get a JavaScript `Date` object, then use the normal [`Date` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) `getDate()`, `getMonth()` (remember that goes 0-11) and `getFullYear()` (or the UTC equivalents like `getUTCDate()`).